# how to modify htaccess file to allow access to private directory from wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, file-upload

I am building a membership website where there will be files that need to available publicly (website assets) and files that needs to be private for members only.

I have created a directory within my uploads folder which I named 'private' and have set the root .htaccess to the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*wp-content/uploads/private/.*
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/(private/.*)$ wp-private.php?file=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I then followed the instructions here to access files in the private directory: https://gist.github.com/hakre/1552239

I have also added some functions within my functions.php to enable a file to be set to private or not:

```
function attachment_fields_to_edit_isprivate( $form_fields, $post ) {
    $isprivate = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_isprivate', true);
    $checked = ($isprivate) ? 'checked' : '';

    $form_fields['isprivate'] = array(
        'label' => 'Private',
        'input' => 'html',
        'html' => "<input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='attachments[{$post->ID}][isprivate]' id='attachments[{$post->ID}][isprivate]' />",
        'value' => $isprivate
    );
    return $form_fields;

}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'attachment_fields_to_edit_isprivate', null, 2 );

function attachment_fields_to_save_isprivate($post, $attachment) {
    $isprivate = ($attachment['isprivate'] == 'on') ? '1' : '0';
    update_post_meta($post['ID'], '_isprivate', $isprivate);
    return $post;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'attachment_fields_to_save_isprivate', null, 2 );


add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'wpse_70093_modify_uploaded_file_title' );

function wpse_70093_modify_uploaded_file_title( $attachment_ID )
{
    $isprivate = get_post_meta($attachment_ID, '_isprivate', true);
    $uploads = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path = $uploads['basedir'];
    $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($attachment_ID);
    $path = pathinfo($upload_path.'/'.$meta['file']);
    if($isprivate == 1){
        rename($path['dirname'].'/'.basename($meta['file']),$uploads['basedir'].'/private/'.basename($meta['file']));
        foreach($meta['sizes'] as $k => $v){
            rename($path['dirname'].'/'.$v['file'],$uploads['basedir'].'/private/'.$v['file']);
        }
        $meta['file'] = 'private/'.basename($meta['file'] );
        update_attached_file( $attachment_ID, 'private/'.basename($meta['file'] ));
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_ID,  $meta );
    }else{
        rename($path['dirname'].'/'.basename($meta['file']),$uploads['basedir'].$uploads['subdir'].'/'.basename($meta['file']));
        foreach($meta['sizes'] as $k => $v){
            rename($path['dirname'].'/'.$v['file'],$uploads['basedir'].$uploads['subdir'].'/'.$v['file']);
        }
        $meta['file'] = ltrim($uploads['subdir'], '/').'/'.basename($meta['file'] );
        update_attached_file( $attachment_ID, ltrim($uploads['subdir'], '/').'/'.basename($meta['file'] ));
        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_ID,  $meta );
    }

}
```

When the file is set to private, my function will move the files from the uploads directory to the private directory and when the file is not set to private it will reverse this.

My issue is that when I set the file to private, wp-admin fails to read the file due to the htaccess that I have set.

Is there a away I can set the htaccess so I can view the private files from wp-admin?

Alternatively, if anyone has a better or more elegant solution to what I am trying achieve without using a plugin I would really appreciate it, as I feel what I am doing right here is too much of a hack.

UPDATE:
This is a screenshot of what happens in the media manager...

[image]

Comment: htaccess-wise, you could only check the referrer - but that would compromise the whole system you are trying to build; anyone could fake it and get access to the files that way. // But your requests for those files are rewritten to your wp-private.php anyway, so why not implement a check in there? Something like if the user is admin, WP has functions for that.

Comment: there is a check in the wp-private.php to allow access to the files if you are admin, however i only know how to apply this file access in my theme templates. the issue i am having is in the media manager where files are getting displayed using their absolute file path and i dont know how to modify this to get the private files within the media manager to display the files via wp-private.php?file=filename

Comment: @CBros is my current htaccess setup secure, i only ask as i dont have much experience with htaccess and referrers, which is the main reason i submitted this question

Comment: _"in the media manager where files are getting displayed using their absolute file path"_ - you mean an absolute URL? _"how to modify this to get the private files within the media manager to display the files via wp-private.php?file=filename"_ - I thought your rewriting was taking care of that?

Comment: i am sorry, i did mean to say absolute URL. my rewriting could take care of it if the images in the media manager were loaded like this <img src="wp-private.php?file=filename"/> but instead they are getting loaded by their absolute url

Comment: So how is your RewriteRule not taking care of this already then?

Comment: i have updated the question with a screenshot where i am having the issue

Comment: I know which section in the back-end you mean … but I still don’t see how this can be a problem, if your RewriteRule catches those URLs and rewrites them to your wp-private.php script? That can only mean that either your rewriting does not work correctly here (which is unlikely, since you say it works for the same image URLs outside of the admin area) - or your script does not do what you said it did.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe, your comments has made me question the code i have implemented within wp-private.php and i found out that it was an error in the script.
i had this in my wp-private.php: $file =  rtrim($basedir,'/').'/'.str_replace('..', '', isset($_GET[ 'file' ])? '/private/'.$_GET[ 'file' ]:'');
which i have replaced to:  $file =  rtrim($basedir,'/').'/'.str_replace('..', '', isset($_GET[ 'file' ])?$_GET[ 'file' ]:'');